# How to Compare two string and find the difference using C# Code

Tags: c#

I want to compare two strings

```
string1 = "My Name is Something. I do nothing"
string2 = "My Name is Momething. I do othing"
```

and the result should be
"My Name is ***Momething***. I do ***othing***"

the diffrence in the word should be shown in differnt font or color

I tried

```
var difference = string1.Except(string2).ToArray()
```

which give the array of diffence

Comment: I tried this " var difference = string1.Except(string2).ToArray() " this will give the array of differnces

Comment: Can anyone tell me why downvoted??

Comment: @Ravi - Downvotes are probably because you did not show what you have tried at first. Then question looks like "do my work for me" which is a legitimate reason for downvoting. I recommend properly reading through the How To Ask :)

Comment: @Esperento57 - no.. There were 10 mins the question was posted with no code. The comment including the code came 4 mins after posting (this should not be in comment) and still up to now there is still no explanation what is the UI that is being used - for the coloring part. I agree with giving time to fix before downvoting. That is what I usually do but the question was not properly posed by how SO expects

Comment: html is used for the result

Comment: Ok, i believe you, mea culpa then ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) on a collection takes all the items of the first collection except (by types equality) items in the second. As your types are `string`s they are collections of `char`s. You do not want `Except` but to check which words are different.

Use `Split` to get a collection of strings, where each is a word, and then use [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare words of same position in sentence:

```
var string1 = "My Name is Something. I do nothing";
var string2 = "My Name is Momething. I do othing";

var result = string1.Split(' ').Zip(string2.Split(' '), (s1, s2) => new { s1, s2 })
                    .Where(p => p.s1 != p.s2);
```

---

If you want to make sure you do not have sections of only spaces you can split like this too:

```
Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

---

To put it back into a single string with marking the differences (for example surrounding it with `<b>` for html bold you can do this:

```
var result = string.Join(" ", string1.Split(' ')
                       .Zip(string2.Split(' '), (s1, s2) => new { s1, s2 })
                       .Select(pair => pair.s1 != pair.s2 ? $"<b>{pair.s2}</b>" : pair.s1));
```

Comment: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,string>>} in result

Comment: i am getting this in var result

Comment: @Ravi - that is because linq is deffered executed. Add `ToList()` or when debugging view the `Results View` - it will execute the query and show you the results

Comment: @Ravi - with no explanation what UI you are working with there is no way to make your text bold. What UI are you using?

Comment: make the text with different color

Comment: This code doeasnt work if he have not same words count

Comment: thanx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

try this, this code compare word by word, same if your string dont have same words number:

```
string string1 = "My Name is Something. I do nothing tessst";
string string2 = "My Name is Momething. I do othing";

//Trasnforme string to list with space like separator, and compare string by position
var List1 = string1.Split(' ').Select((valuestring1, index) => new { valuestring1, index });
var List2 = string2.Split(' ').Select((valuestring2, index) => new { valuestring2, index });

//Left outer join
var leftdifference = from word1 in List1
                     from word2 in List2.Where(word2 => word1.index == word2.index).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where word2 == null || word1.valuestring1 != word2.valuestring2
                     select new { word1, word2 };

//Right outer join
var rightdifference = from word2 in List2
                      from word1 in List1.Where(word1 => word1.index == word2.index).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where word1 == null || word1.valuestring1 != word2.valuestring2
                      select new { word1, word2 };

var fulldifference = leftdifference.Union(rightdifference).ToList();

foreach (var item in fulldifference)
{
    string val1 = item.word1 == null ? "NOT PRESENT WORD" : item.word1.valuestring1;
    string val2 = item.word2 == null ? "NOT PRESENT WORD" : item.word2.valuestring2;
    int index = item.word1 == null ? item.word2.index : item.word1.index;

    Console.WriteLine("position {0}, string1 : '{1}' , string2 : '{2}'", index, val1, val2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are trying this on web or something else, for console app:

---

```
string[] strArr1 = string1.Split(' ').ToArray();
string[] strArr2 = string2.Split(' ').ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < strArr1.Length; i++)
{
    if(string.Compare(strArr1[i], strArr2[i]) != 0)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write(strArr2[i]);
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(strArr2[i] + " ");
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Though not direct answer, but you may solve your problem with the functionality from the tool i've written for string comparison result in percentage. I've hosted here https://rajavenkatesh.com/DamLevDisDescription.aspx